# Laravel Rest API image upload in React Native app

Tags: php, laravel, react-native, azure-devops-rest-api

I what to upload image using Laravel rest API, but there is some issue

i am using [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker)

here is the response of image picker

```
 LOG  FileName :  {"fileName": "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_ff6cf0af-08b3-41ff-8f76-81a744d42ad4.jpg", 
"fileSize": 37514, "height": 2400, "type": "image/jpeg",
"uri": "file:///data/user/0/com.hometutorsclub/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_ff6cf0af-08b3-41ff-8f76-81a744d42ad4.jpg", "width": 1080}
```

and using this method to upload

```
 var data = new FormData();
  
      data.append('img', {
        uri : imageObj.uri,
        type: imageObj.type,
        name: imageObj.fileName,
      });
```

here is API configuration to upload image

[Laravel Rest API configuration of image upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fegZl.png)

with this config, image is uploading properly on POSTMAN but in React Native app is not uploading

**i think frontend and backend config not communicating to upload it**

can you please help me where is the issue

Answer (score 0):

As It's working on Postman, it may be a header issue.
While sending your request using Postman, take a look at the hidden generated headers and find out which one is missed in your react request.
Most likely, it is a Content-Type issue. I can see this header in my Postman headers while uploading an image:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>
```

Comment: Yes, i see there is a boundary=<calculated when request is sent> in postman Header, witch i was not added in my header,

but Know issue is how i can add boundary
`Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>`
its give me syntax error & when i write is witch string  
` "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>",`
it's not working

Comment: ok. just try Content-Type: multipart/form-data record